# How do I get coordinates of a surface of a loaded OBJ/MTL model?

Tags: 3d, coordinates, three.js

EDIT EDIT:

I also should mention my model is scaled. I am not sure if this impacts the intersectsObject method.. But it obviously impacts a line that I am trying to draw onto and measure in meters (using a known ratio). This line is does not always map to the correct surface.. what do I need to do to fix this?

**To clarify:**

**I need to measure a line after selecting two points on the surface of a model, and output this in metres. However, using my model, it would seem that I cannot select every point on every surface on the model, and sometimes it selects other points behind surfaces (relative to the camera of course)...**

Does anyone have any insight into this? Some of the surfaces are planes, as in no thickness - maybe this is a problem.

---

EDIT: so  I got this working by calling the overloaded method for ray.intersectsObjects..
which is called using:

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

However, **It does not work for every surface on the model.. Any ideas?**

---

So I have a model of a building loaded in webGL using three.js, specifically loaded using the OBJMTL loader.

using the conventional way, i.e

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

// create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

I am unable to find any objects when my mouse is hovering over the model, and the debugger says that intersects isn't initialized..

I load my building like this

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

var object = event.content;

object.position.y = 8;
object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 8;
scene.add( object );
objects.push(object);

});
loader.load( 'oakley/building.obj', 'oakley/building.mtl' );
```

where you can see the scene.add() call.

So, am I doing something stupid, or is there just no way to detect face collision of a loaded model using this way?

If not, is there a work around?

Comment: It's really not clear from your question what exactly are you asking for.. some images with scene and the problem might increase your change for some answers..

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ycbfe

I cannot measure the 'thin' sides.. the main bulk of the building seems to work, just the thin walls work sporadically.

Comment: So you're trying to implement 'object picking'. The raycasting/tracing solution i quite problematic due to numerical precision problems. I didn't find that three.js supports picking some way, so you'll have to implement that by yourself. Here are some [basic ideas for start](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=3336).